# Is there a conditional random variable?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a sample space.

Let $F $ be a $\sigma$-subalgebra of $\Sigma$ and let $X$ be a real-valued random variable.

So what does it mean $X/F$? How is this defined mathematically and books to read?

Comment: Caution: X/F does not exists.

Comment: I found it in an article, and it confuses me because I do not know how to interpret it.

Comment: You might have found E(X|F), not X|F (or X/F) in isolation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a R.V. on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}_0, P)$ such that $E|X| < \infty$.

$E[X \mid \mathcal{F}]$ where $\mathcal{F}$ a $\sigma$-algebra such that $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{F}_0 $is any random variable $Y$ (called a ``version'' of $E[X \mid \mathcal{F}]$) that satisfies:

1) $Y$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable

2) for all $A  \in \mathcal{F}$, $\int_A X \, dP = \int_A Y \, dP$

It exists and is unique.

A good book to read is Durrett's Probability: Theory and Examples (now in its 4th edition but a 2nd or 3rd edition is fine) - this definition is taken from the 3rd edition, section 4.1.

Comment: Actually I knew all that, thanks anyway for responding!